# RxSwift `ActivityIndicator` Functionality in Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, rx-swift, combine

I've been working with RxSwift for a few years now, and am starting to explore Combine with SwiftUI and am having some trouble trying to replicate some functionality from RxSwift in Combine.

On the RxSwift [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift) there is an example in a file called `ActivityIndicator.swift`.

Basic usage is as follows:

```
class Foo {
  let activityIndicator = ActivityIndicator()

  lazy var activity = activityIndicator.asDriver()

  var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  func doSomething() {
    Observable
      .just("this is something")
      .trackActivity(activityIndicator)
      .subscribe()
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

What this does is allow you to then drive off of the `activity` driver and it will emit boolean values every time something subscribes or a subscription completes.

You can then directly drive something like a UIActivityIndicatorView's isAnimating property using RxCocoa.

I've been trying to figure out how to create something similar to this in Combine but am not having any luck.

Say I have a viewModel that looks like this:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isActive = false

  func doSomething() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
    Just(())
      .delay(for: 2.0, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is create an operator for a `Publisher` that will function similarly to how the Rx operator worked where I can forward the events from the subscription through the chain, but change the `isActive` value every time something subscribes/completes/cancels.

In the SwiftUI View I would initiate the `doSomething` function and sink to it, while also being able to use the published `isActive` property to show/hide a `ProgressView`

Something similar to this:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
  let viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    var cancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    VStack {
      Text("This is text")

      if viewModel.isActive {
        ProgressView()
      }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
      viewModel
        .doSomething()
        .sink()
        .store(in: &cancelBag)
    })
  }
}
```

Is there something that works like this already that I am just completely missing?

If not, how can I go about replicating the RxSwift functionality in Combine?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone created a Combine version. I don't know if it has the same issue as discussed by @Daniel T. but it looks promising.
https://github.com/duyquang91/ActivityIndicator

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for relaying that here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... The key to the `ActivityIndicator` class is the `Observable.using(_:observableFactory:)` operator. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is an equivalent operator in Combine.

The using operator creates a resource when the Observable is subscribed to, and then disposes the resource when the Observable sends a stop event (complete or error.) This insures the resource's lifetime. In this particular case, the resource just increments an Int value on creation and decrements it on disposal.

I think you could kind of mimic the behavior with something like this:

```
extension Publisher {
    func trackActivity(_ activityIndicator: CombineActivityIndicator) -> some Publisher {
        return activityIndicator.trackActivity(of: self)
    }
}

final class CombineActivityIndicator {
    var counter = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    var cancelables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func trackActivity<Source: Publisher>(of source: Source) -> some Publisher {
        let sharedSource = source.share()
        counter.value += 1
        sharedSource
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { [unowned self] _ in
                    self.counter.value -= 1
                },
                receiveValue: { _ in }
            )
            .store(in: &cancelables)
        return sharedSource
    }

    var asPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        counter
            .map { $0 > 0 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

However, the above class will heat up the Publisher and you might miss emitted values because of it. Use at your own risk, I do not recommend the above unless you are desperate.

Maybe someone has written a `using` operator for Publisher and will be willing to share.

Comment: What do you mean by "heat up the Publisher"? Is that something a lock could fix?

Comment: By sharing the publisher and then calling sink on it, the publisher is free to start emitting events. If your other Subscriber hasn't connected yet, you would miss events. I don't think a lock would help.

Comment: Would implementing a shareReplay operator help? That way all new subscribers would get the last value emitted? I think I've seen an implementation of one somewhere.

Comment: That just moves the goalpost. So if two events emit before you subscribe, then you loose the first one. I guess if you did an unbounded share replay, but sounds like a huge waste of resources.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I'm gonna chalk this one up to not possible at the moment and continue to explore other options. Maybe someone will implement a using operator someday.

Comment: You could use [RxCombine](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/RxCombine) which allows you to convert between RxSwift and Combine. That way you can use the limited functionality of Combine when you can and drop back into RxSwift when you must.